# Google Analytics with Tag Manager in Ajax Application

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have implemented Google Tag manager on my SPA. Currently, I am serving virtual page views to the dataLayer like so:

```
    dataLayer.push({'event': 'virtualPageView', 'virtualUrl': '/Account/Home', 'virtualTitle': 'Logged in Homepage'});
```

This dataLayer is doing everything correctly, but for some reason when I first come to the homepage, analytics sees index.html still. But if the user goes to another page and then back to their Account homepage, analytics registers it as "Logged in Homepage" - like I tell it to.

Any insight into this?

Comment: what exactly is the problem? Do you not want analytics to register 'index.html' the first time? I don't think you can hide the built-in events of page views, but you should *also* see a virtualPageView trigger fire. Do you not?

Comment: Correct, I don't want analytics to register index.html the first time. I want it to register the page as 'account/home' like I specify in the virtualPageView

Comment: I don't think you can stop it from registering the built-in events. But you shouldn't need to; just use your custom event, or write a trigger with more specific conditionals. Otherwise, can you explain more about your use case?